# angular : get json value from interval with http get and subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to polling data from a webservice each second. I use that code in my ts component, and the web service is called normally.

```
interval(1000) // run every 1 second
    .pipe(
      startWith(0),
      switchMap(nbprofil => this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/api/profils?title=' + this.input.nativeElement.value + '&area=' + this.searchMoviesCtrl.value + '&nb=true')
      ))
    .subscribe(
      res =>  res['nbprofil'],
      error => {}
    );
```

The result of the webservice is for example {"nbprofil": 566}
Now I would like to use the value of nbprofil(here value is 566) to display it in a variable on  my html file like :

```
<h1>Polling Value: {{nbprofil}}</h1>
```

The question is How can I get value from subscribe res ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: Continous polling without closing impending requests isn't a good idea. To use the response, you need to assign it to a member variable, for eg. `res => this.nbprofil = res['nbprofil']` and use it in the template like `{{ nbprofil }}`.

Answer (score 2):

you can create a variable in your component to hold the Observable itself.

```
intervalCall$: Observable<any>;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  this.intervalCall$ = interval(1000) // run every 1 second
    .pipe(
      startWith(0),
      switchMap(nbprofil => this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/api/profils?title=' + this.input.nativeElement.value + '&area=' + this.searchMoviesCtrl.value + '&nb=true')
      ))
}
```

In your HTML, you can display the data by doing:

```
<ng-container *ngIf = 'intervalCall$ | async as data'>
  <p>{{data | json}}</p>
</ng-container>
```

The advantage in using the `async` pipe is that we don't need to worry about unsubscribing as the pipe does this for us. The above HTML will also only display the data when it is returned from the server.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I like the autounsubscribe method. Do you have any idea to use this value with <mat-paginator> <mat-paginator *ngIf = 'intervalCall$ | async as data'>
      [length]={{data.nbprofil | json}} [pageSize]="10" showFirstLastButtons>
    </mat-paginator>

Answer (score 1):

In service(dataservice) have this :-

```
public getData() {
    return interval(1000) // run every 1 second
        .pipe(
          startWith(0),
          switchMap(nbprofil => this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/api/profils?title=' + this.input.nativeElement.value + '&area=' + this.searchMoviesCtrl.value + '&nb=true')
          ))
}
```

In Component :-

```
public nbProfil;

this.dataservice.getData.subscribe(res=> this.nbProfil = res['nbProfil']);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
nbprofil: string;
ngOnInit(): void {

  interval(1000) // run every 1 second
    .pipe(
      startWith(0),
      switchMap(nbprofil => this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/api/profils?title=' + this.input.nativeElement.value + '&area=' + this.searchMoviesCtrl.value + '&nb=true')
      ))
    .subscribe(
      res =>  this.nbprofil = res['nbprofil'],
      error => {}
    );
}
```

```
<h1>Polling Value: {{this.nbprofil}}</h1>
```